# What is fusion in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc, stream-fusion

Every now and again I have been noticing the following in Haskell documentation:
(for example in [`Data.Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html)):

> Subject to fusion

What is *fusion* and how do I use it?

Comment: The accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578063/what-is-haskells-stream-fusion is about the `stream-fusion` library, which has not compiled for years. It predates the general use of the `text` and `vector` libraries, which do use stream fusion, and do compile, and are fundamental to modern Haskell. The author of the accepted answer seems to be completely ignorant of the existence of these libraries. Read today, the accepted answer is basically disinformation, and anyway does not give the advice asked for above when genuine worthwhile advice really does exist.

Comment: @Michael I completely disagree with your point of view. The answer is just **old**. If you think that it would be more useful to have an updated answer to that question just *answer it yourself* instead of blaming a 7 years old answer.

Comment: @Bukuriu I wasn't objecting to that answer to that question, which was posed then, but to closing this one as a duplicate. Or are you suggesting that  I should add a new answer to a question that was asked seven years ago?

Comment: thx @Michael, this page is now the top result when googling "haskell fusion", and IMHO your comment triggers the right amount of distrust in order to read those answers in a scrutinizing way. (though, i do not believe in the ignorance of that person.) the answer you were referring to is NOT the answer below, readers should be aware and compare. though, the TL;DR answer that i was looking for, i found in the haskell wiki: https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC_optimisations#Fusion

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In general, fusion refers to transformations whose purpose is to get rid of   intermediate data structures. You *fuse* function calls that result in wasteful memory allocations into something more efficient. This is actually IMO one of the biggest applications of Haskell being pure. And you pretty much don't need to do anything to get it, it comes for free through the GHC compiler.

#### Haskell is pure

Because Haskell is pure, we get this thing called [referential transparency](https://wiki.haskell.org/Referential_transparency), which (from the link), means that "expression always evaluates to the same result in any context"<sup>1</sup>. That means that I can do very general program level manipulations without changing what the program will actually output. For example, even without knowing what `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` are I always know that

```
 ((x ++ y) ++ z) ++ w
```

will evaluate to the same thing as

```
 x ++ (y ++ (z ++ w))
```

yet the second one will in practice involve less memory allocations (since `x ++ y` requires reallocating whole prefix of the output list).

#### Rewrite rules

In fact, there are a whole lot of this sort of optimization we can do, and, because Haskell is pure, we can basically just move whole expressions around (replacing `x`, `y`, `z`, or `w` for actual lists or expressions that evaluate to lists in the example above changes nothing). This becomes a pretty mechanical process.

Furthermore, it turns out that you can come up with a lot of equivalences for higher order functions ([Theorems for free!](https://www.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf)). For example,

```
map f (map g xs) = map (f . g) xs
```

no matter what `f`, `g`, and `xs` are (the two sides are semantically equal). Yet while the two sides of this equation produce the same value output, the left hand side is always worse in efficiency: it ends up allocating space for an intermediate list `map g xs`, that is immediately thrown away. We'd like to tell the compiler to, whenever it encounters something like `map f (map g xs)`, replace it with `map (f . g) xs`. And, for GHC, that is through [rewrite rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#rewrite-rules):

```
{-# RULES     "map/map"    forall f g xs.  map f (map g xs) = map (f.g) xs #-}
```

The `f`, `g`, and `xs` can be matched against any expressions, not just variables (so something like `map (+1) (map (*2) ([1,2] ++ [3,4]))` gets transformed into `map ((+1) . (*2)) ([1,2] ++ [3,4])`. ([There doesn't appear to be a good way to search for rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651602/searching-for-rewrite-rules), so I compiled a [list](https://gist.github.com/harpocrates/e95ce275a2220dfbd50b102e1e533556)). [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.89.3092&rep=rep1&type=pdf) explains the motivation and workings of GHC rewrite rules.

#### So that's how GHC optimizes `map`?

Actually, not quite. The thing above is [short-cut fusion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Short_cut_fusion). The name sort of implies the drawback: it doesn't scale too well and is annoying to debug. You end up having to write a ton of ad-hoc rules for all arrangements of the same common functions. Then, you hope that repeated application of rewrite rules will simplify your expressions nicely.

It turns out that we can do even better in some cases by organizing our re-write rules so that we build up some intermediate normal form and then have  rules targeting that intermediate form. This way, we start getting "hot" paths of rewrite rules.

Probably the most advanced of these systems is [stream fusion](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.7401&rep=rep1&type=pdf) targeting coinductive sequences (basically lazy sequences like lists). Check out [this thesis](http://community.haskell.org/~duncan/thesis.pdf) and [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/ndp/haskell-beats-C.pdf) (which is actually pretty much how the [`vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) package is implemented). For example, in `vector`, your code gets first transformed into an intermediate form involving `Stream`s and `Bundle`s, is optimized in that form, then gets transformed back into vectors.

#### And... `Data.Text`?

`Data.Text` uses stream fusion to minimize the number of memory allocations that occur (I think this is especially important for the strict variant). If you check out the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/src/Data-Text.html#pack), you'll see that the functions "subject to fusion" actually manipulate [`Stream`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text-Internal-Fusion.html) for the most part (they are of the general form `unstream . (stuff manipulating stream) . stream`) and there are a bunch of `RULES` pragmas for transforming `Stream`s. In the end, any combination of these functions is supposed to get fused so that only one allocation needs to occur.

#### So, what do I need to take away for my everyday coding?

The only real way to know when your code is subject to fusion is to have a good understanding of the rewrite rules involved and understand well how GHC works. That said, there is one thing that you *should* do: try to use non-recursive higher order functions when possible, since these can be (at least for now, but in general will always be more) easily fused.

#### Complications

Because fusion in Haskell occurs through repeated application of rewrite rules, it suffices to convince yourself of each rewrite rule's correctness to know that the whole "fused" program does the same thing as your original program does. Except there are edge cases relating to programs terminating. For example, one might think that

```
 reverse (reverse xs) = xs
```

yet that is clearly not true, since `head $ reverse (reverse [1..])` will not terminate yet `head [1..]` will. [More information from the Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Correctness_of_short_cut_fusion).

---

<sup>1</sup> This is actually true only provided that in these contexts the expression maintains the same type.

Comment: Nitpicking: referential transparecy does **not** work in *any* context. Only in contexts where the types of the names are preserved.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deforestation_(computer_science)

Comment: The fact that this gold star of an answer only has 12 upvotes is sad. This was really informative. Thank you.

Comment: @Alxandr that sort of comment is worth much more than upvotes. Glad to know I helped!

Comment: Regarding "map f (map g xs) = map (f . g) xs", in what sense "the left hand side is always worse in efficiency"? I suppose

map f (map g xs) ==eval==> map f (map g (headxs : tailxs)) ==eval==>
map f ( (g headxs) : (map g tailxs) ) ==eval==> 
(f (g headxs)) : (map f (map g tailxs)),

while 

map (f . g) xs ==eval==> map (f . g) (headxs : tailxs) ==eval==>
((f . g) headxs) : (map (f . g) tailxs) ==eval==>
(f (g headxs)) : (map (f . g) tailxs)

How is the first one worse than the second?

Comment: @haskelllooksgreat the LHS ends up allocating an intermediate list (for `map g xs`) as well as the output list (for `map f (map g xs)`) while the RHS only allocates the one output list.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you explain why do you say: “ yet the second one will in practice involve less memory allocations (since x ++ y requires reallocating whole prefix of the output list” ?

Comment: @F.Zer `x ++ y` will create a new list by prepending each element of `x` to the second list, `y`. For each element in `x`, this means an operation on the list and a memory allocation. Thus, `x++(y++z)` will first prepend elements of `y`, then those from `x` (a total of `lenght x + lenght y`)  BUT `(x++y)++z` will first prepend elements of `x` to `y` then all these elements from `x` and `y` will be prepended to `z` (with a total of `2 * length x + length y` operations/allocations).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

**Fusion is to intermediate data structures what inlining is to functions.**

It is an optimization technique done by the compiler.
The compiler might need the support of some (sometimes hand written) transformation rules in order to make more things fuse than only the obvious things.

---

In many imperative languages only functions/subroutines can be inlined.
In Haskell can be done more: Inlining functions might create funny situations like this:

```
case (if a==b then Just 42 else Nothing) of
    Just x -> print x
    Nothing -> return ()
```

The result would now be thanks to Fusion:

```
if a==b then print 42 else return ()
```

In order to use this optimization more often, some [transformation rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.8.1/docs/users_guide/exts/rewrite_rules.html) might need to exist, like i.e.

```
{-# RULES
  "map/map"    forall f g xs.  map f (map g xs) = map (f . g) xs
#-}
```

... so that `f` and `g` can fuse here. We then say, that `map f` and `map g` in `map f . map g` also fuse, and not only in the obvious way of creating a list and consuming it, but also deeper: between `f` and `g`.

Also, see
https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC_optimisations#Fusion