# How to do inverse series sum in haskell efficiently?

Tags: haskell

This is the code I am trying to convert in haskell. But immutability creates the problem. How to do calculation without mutable variables. Creating a list of `[1..20]` and mapping over it doesn't seem like space efficient. Is there any trick or techniques to escape immutability?

```
int main()
{
    int i,n=0;
    double sum= 0.0;
    for ( i=1; i<20; ++i )
    {
        n += i;
        sum = 1 / (double) n;
    }
    printf("The sum is: %lf",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haskell can probably iterate over the list without materializing it, so maybe there is no space wasted.

Comment: @Thilo even keeping that in mind, still computation requires little bit of mutation. *The reason why we don't mark everything `const` in C*. Not an argument but the idea of everything immutable itches me sometimes. But Thanks for clearing my doubt up ! :)

Comment: @GauravP - if you are summing reciprocals of `n` you should fix your C code: `sum += 1 / (double) n`

Comment: @GauravP You are underestimating the amount of work the compiler can do. Things in Haskell are immutable by default; this *decreases* the overhead because the compiler can make optimizations that a C compiler cannot because immutability is already guaranteed.

Comment: @ErikR not exactly the sum of reciprocals. It's modified for a math problem I have in an assignment. It needs the 'n' to be the sum of 1 to 'i' in each iteration 'i'.

Comment: Even if the list is materialized, in the sense that all reference to it does not disappear with build/foldr fusion, no more than one element need be in memory at a time, due to laziness and gc.

Comment: @chepner I think I have to change my mind. But I was missing one thing that is the compiler is very smart in Haskell. I feel bad because I have hard time grasping immutable concept. Any advice for me from you. *I am going for functional programming over object oriented*

Comment: @Michael That makes sense actually ! After all haskell is lazy. It will never do anything that can be avoided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `scanl1` to generate your list of `n`s:

```
> scanl1 (+) $ [1..19]
[1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55,66,78,91,105,120,136,153,171,190]
```

From there, it is a simple matter to compute the inverses

```
> map (1/) . scanl1 (+) $ [1..19]
[1.0,0.3333333333333333,0.16666666666666666, ...]
```

and sum them:

```
> sum . map (1/) . scanl1 (+) $ [1..19]
1.8999999999999997
```

Although the *Haskell* code treats values as immutable and it appears you are generating a bunch of intermediate lists, the compiler is smart enough to generate efficient *executable* code.

Comment: Or, use math `2-2/(n+1)=1.9`

Comment: Yes, that would apply to the original C code as well. We're trying to point out that what is a bad idea in C isn't necessarily a bad idea in Haskell.

Comment: I'm waiting for the day compilers to get smart enough to perform these higher level optimizations...

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. And the last output is also identical to that of C. Thank You ! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can examine the code that GHC generates with `-ddump-asm`.

Compile this program:

```
main = print $ 1.0 / fromIntegral (sum [(1::Int)..12345])
```

with:

```
$ ghc -O2 Main.hs -ddump-asm > asm-output
```

Then have a look at `asm-output`, search for `12345` and you will see this loop:

```
_c47b:
        addq %r14,%rsi
        incq %r14
_c476:
        cmpq $12345,%r14
        jne _c47b
```

This shows that the list `[1..12345]` is not actually created.

**Update**

It seems you intended to sum the reciprocals of the triangular numbers,
i.e. 1/1 + 1/3 + 1/6 + ... That is, you intended to write:

```
sum += 1.0 / (double) n;
```

This can be expressed in Haskell as:

```
main = print $ sum $ map (\x -> 1 / (fromIntegral x)) $ scanl (+) 1 [(2::Int)..12345]
```

Examining the generated assembly we see again that no intermediate list is created:

```
_c4ao:
        cvtsi2sdq %rsi,%xmm0
        movsd _n4aP(%rip),%xmm2
        divsd %xmm0,%xmm2
        addsd %xmm2,%xmm1
        incq %r14
_c4ad:
        addq %r14,%rsi
        cmpq $12345,%r14
        jne _c4ao
```

Here `%r14` is the counter `i` in your C code, `%rsi` is the variable `n` and `%xmm1` is the accumulator `sum`.

Answer (score 3):

To temporarily escape the immutability you can use [the `ST` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html).

However there's no need for that. In the following expression everything will be optimised out by the compiler due to [Stream Fusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578063/what-is-haskells-stream-fusion):

```
sum (map (\n -> 1 / fromIntegral n) [1..20])
```

Comment: note I'm also incrementing n with each iteration so it goes like 1,3,6,10 so on up to 20. i and n is changing simultaneously. Thanks a lot I was looking for that escaping immutability. ST monad. Great resource.

Comment: Data.List uses foldr/build fusion, which is basically the exact opposite of stream fusion.

Comment: I wish we'd stop referencing that answer. To much of the information in it is outdated. For example, the default Prelude list functions have had stream fusion for a while now... The first comment on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905369/what-is-fusion-in-haskell) question sort of says it.