# Deforestation in a Hylomorphism

Tags: haskell, ghc, recursion-schemes

Wikipedia writes about [Hylomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylomorphism_(computer_science)):

> In [...] functional programming a hylomorphism is a recursive
>   function,  corresponding to the composition of an anamorphism (which
>   first builds a set of results;  also known as 'unfolding')  followed
>   by a catamorphism (which then folds these results into a final return
>   value).  Fusion of these two recursive computations into a single
>   recursive pattern then **avoids  building the intermediate data
>   structure**. This is an example of deforestation,  a program
>   optimization strategy.

(Bold markup by me)

Using the [recursion-schemes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes) library
I wrote a very simple hylomorphism:

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show $ hylosum 1000

hylosum :: Int -> Int
hylosum end = hylo alg coalg 1
  where 
    -- Create list of Int's from 1 to n
    coalg :: Int -> ListF Int Int
    coalg n 
       | n > end = Nil
       | otherwise = Cons n (n + 1)
    -- Sum up a list of Int's
    alg :: ListF Int Int -> Int
    alg Nil  =  0
    alg (Cons a x) = a + x
```

In the cabal file I instructed GHC to optimize the code:

```
name:                Hylo
version:             0.1.0.0
synopsis:            Hylomorphisms and Deforestation        
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable             Hylo
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -O2
  build-depends:       base >=4.10 && <4.11 , recursion-schemes      
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Using stackage lts-10.0 (GHC 8.2.2) I compile with `stack build` and run with `stack exec Hylo -- +RTS -s` and I get:

```
500500
      84,016 bytes allocated in the heap
       3,408 bytes copied during GC
      44,504 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
      25,128 bytes maximum slop
           2 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
```

Now I change `hylosum 1000` to `hylosum 1000000`  (1000 times more) and I get:

```
500000500000
  16,664,864 bytes allocated in the heap
      16,928 bytes copied during GC
  15,756,232 bytes maximum residency (4 sample(s))
      29,224 bytes maximum slop
          18 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
```

So heap usage goes up from 84 KB to 16,664 KB. This is 200 times more than before. 
Therefore I think, GHC does not do the deforestation / fusion mentioned in wikipedia!

This is not really a surprise: The anamorphism creates the list items from left to right 
(from 1 to n) and the catamorphism consumes the items the opposite way from right to left
(from n to 1) and it's difficult to see how the hylomorphism can work 
without creating the whole intermediate list.

Questions: 
Is GHC able to perform the deforestation? 
If *yes*, what do I have to change in my code or cabal file?
If *yes*, how does it really work? 
if *no*, where is the issue: in wikipedia, GHC or in the library?

Comment: Deforestation ~ fusion. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905369/what-is-fusion-in-haskell/38910170#38910170

Comment: TL;DR this doesn't really happen all that automatically: sometimes GHC's inlining is enough, but usually you'll need some rewrite rules.

Comment: @Alec: So every user of the hylo function must write these rewrite rules himself? How are these rewrite rules for my case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The data structure is actually fused away, but the resulting program is not tail recursive. The optimized code basically looks like this (with no `Cons` or `Nil` in sight):

```
h n | n > end = 0
    | otherwise = n + h (n+1)
```

To evaluate the result you must first evaluate `h (n+1)` recursively, and then add the result to `n`. During the recursive call, the value `n` must remain stored somewhere, hence we observe increased memory usage as `end` increases.

A tighter loop can be obtained by having the recursive call be in tail position, and carry a constant size accumulator. We want the code to optimize to this instead:

```
-- with BangPatterns
h n !acc | n > end = acc
         | otherwise = h (n+1) (n + acc)
```

In `hylosum`, the call to `(+)` happens in `alg`, and we replace that with a call to a continuation that will be built up by `hylo`.

```
alg :: ListF Int (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
alg Nil acc = acc
alg (Cons n go) !acc = go (n + acc)
```

With that I see a constant 51kB allocated in the heap.